# Check if url exist in array list of URLS retrieved from database

Tags: php

I am trying to compare the current URL with the URLs retrieved from the database but for some reason only works if it matches the first array.

```
   $url = get_permalink();
function check_links($url){
    $db_links= get_option('db_links'); 
         
    $exclude = explode(',',$db_links); 

    if(in_array($url, $exclude)){
          echo "display:none"; 
        } 

}
```

After I dump $exclude, I get

```
array(3){
    [0]=>string(16) "https://test.com"
    [1]=>string(18) "https://test.com/2"
    [2]=>string(19) "https://test.com/22"
    [3]=>string(20) "https://test.com/235"
}
```

I want to compare my current URL with the list above. If it shows I want to echo `"display:none";`
My current URL is https://test.com/22

```
if(in_array($url, $exclude)){
  echo "display:none"; 
}
```

I found out that it works only if my URL is https://test.com, for other cases it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Where are you defining `$url`

Comment: I find it very weird that all the keys of the array are 0, it should be 0, 1, 2, 3..., not all the same.

Comment: @DarkBee $url is get_permalink() wordpress function. I call this function check_links($url) in footer and pass $url value I got with get_permalink()

Comment: @Armando error when copying

Comment: Geez, I don't have any plausible explanation for what you are experiencing, I just tried by copying your array and your url and it works.

Answer (score 1):

In this case your string have some `\n` and `space` than not showed and which cause errors, for handeling this errors you most replace the `\n\` and `space` with nothing, folow mycode:

```php
$url = get_permalink();
function check_links($url){
    $db_links= get_option('db_links'); 
    $exclude = array_map('trim', explode(',',$db_links)); 

    if(in_array($url, $exclude)){
          echo "display:none"; 
        }
}
```

it will work.